# How to show all ASP.NET web application's loaded/referenced assemblies with version numbers?

Tags: asp.net, reflection, assemblies, version

I'd like to show a list of all used assemblies on a dedicated web page inside a ASP.NET web application for debugging and maintainance purposes (there are many instances of this web application on many different servers). The assemblies could be called from the *bin folder* or from the *GAC*. There are some written by myself, but also third-party assemblies.

Is there a simple, automated way to get a **list of all loaded or referenced assemblies** of the web application including the **version number** (calling `System.Reflection.Assembly` - `GetName().Version` ...)? Do I have to explicitly pass all assembly names for version check or could I retrieve them automatically? Do I have to use Reflection for a comprehensive list of dependencies/references?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() for this, e.g something like this:

```
foreach (System.Reflection.Assembly a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
{
    Response.Write(a.FullName + "<br/>"); 
}
```

Comment: So simple... I think I just have to filter out some temporary assemblies (all the aspx / ascx converted stuff).